# Specifying template parameters on overloaded operator()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-argument-deduction

```cpp
struct foo{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T arg) { return T{}; }
}
```

To use the `operator()`, I would call it like: `foo()(1)`, which `T` would be deduced to `int`.

However, if I want to specify `T` as something else, like `long`, the only way that seems to work is, which kind of defeats the reason of using `operator()`:

```cpp
foo().operator()<long>(1);
```

Is there a better option?

---

I'm thinking about letting `foo` take a template parameter `U` and defaults `U` to `void`; `T` would defaults to `U` if `U` is not `void`. However I'd prefer to only change the `operator()` function. Maybe using a lambda instead?

Comment: `foo()(long{1})`

Comment: If you are going to use `{}` to initialize the `long`, you may as well use it to initialize the `foo`, too: `foo{}(long{1});` However, it would be easier use `1L` or `1l` instead to declare `1` is a `long`, instead of specifying the `long` type explicitly: `foo{}(1L);`

Comment: *SO doesn't let me delete it, so I will edit it instead.* Just ask a new one.  No reason to invalidate answers you've already recieved.

Comment: @NathanOliver You are right, will ask a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`L` or `l` suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) to specify that the integer literal `1` should be treated as a `long` instead of an `int`, eg:

```cpp
foo()(1L)
```